# Basic question for Conditional expectation conditioned on X=x

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

I have a basic question on conditional expectation. First I'll summarize my understandig of them (could be wrong).

On a probablity space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ the conditional expectation 
$\mathbb{E}[ X \vert \mathcal{H} ]$ of an $\mathbb{P}$-integrable random number $X$ conditioned on
a sub-$\sigma$-field $\mathcal{H}\subset \mathcal{A}$ is the almost sure unique 
$\mathbb{P}$-integrable and $\mathcal{H}$-measurable random number $E$ with

\begin{equation}
    \int_A E \; d\mathbb{P} = \int_A X \; d\mathbb{P},
    \qquad\qquad
    \forall \; A\in\mathcal{H}
\end{equation}

In particular $\mathbb{E}[X\vert \mathcal{H}] = \mathbb{E}X$ almost surely, if $X$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are
independent.

If $\mathcal{H}=\sigma H$ for a random variable $H$ in some measurable space $(S,\mathcal{S})$, then 
$\mathbb{E}[ X \vert H ]=\mathbb{E}[X\vert \mathcal{H}]$
has the form $E = f\circ H$ for a $\mathcal{S}$/$\mathcal{B}$-measurable function 
$f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. One writes $\mathbb{E}[ X \vert H=s ] = f(s)$ for $s\in S$.

Now lets say $X$ is of the form $X=g(Y,H)$ for a measurable function $g$ and a random variable $Y$, 
where $Y$ is independent of $H$.

Now the question: What is $\mathbb{E}[ g(Y,H) \vert H=s ]$ ? is it $\mathbb{E}[ g(Y,s) ]$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi(s) = \mathbb E[g(Y, s)]$. Further let $B = H^{-1}(A)\in\sigma (H)$ for some suitable $A\in\mathcal S$. We want to show that
$$ \int_B \phi(H) d\mathbb P = \int_B g(Y, H) d\mathbb P. $$

Say $Y$ maps into the measurable space $(T,\mathcal T)$.
Then, we have
\begin{align} 
\int_B \phi(H(\omega)) \;d\mathbb P(\omega) 
&= \int_\Omega 1_A(H(\omega)) \phi(H(\omega)) \;d\mathbb P(\omega) \\
&= \int_S 1_A(s) \phi(s) \;d(\mathbb P\circ H^{-1})(s) \\
&= \int_S 1_A(s) \int_T g(t, s) \;d(\mathbb P\circ Y^{-1})(t) \;d(\mathbb P\circ H^{-1})(s) \\
&= \int_{T\times S} 1_A(s) g(t, s) \;d(\mathbb P \circ (Y, H)^{-1})(t, s) \\
&= \int_\Omega 1_A(H(\omega)) g(Y(\omega), H(\omega)) \;d\mathbb P(\omega) \\
&= \int_B g(Y(\omega), H(\omega)) \;d\mathbb P(\omega). \\
\end{align}
The 4th equation uses the fact that $Y,H$ are independent.